# Do we need a tag for tutorials, resources and such?

Tags: discussion, tags

Although the site concept discourages questions asking for links, references to tutorials etc... the fact is that we finally have and will keep having such questions. Given that, shall we consider to have one single "Resources-Links" tag for terms like tutorials, learning and such ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little cautious of these types of questions. Extensions recommendations can be a nice, simple and quick question to answer, however it's considered "Primarily Opinion based" which as you know is one of the reasons when flagging to close a question. A lot of the time people may answer the question with simple a mega list of extensions to choose from which in my honest opinion, can be helpful, but in other ways is also not. I simply reminds me of a "Here's a list of things to choose from, enjoy testing them all" scenario which I've seen quite a lot on SO.

One may also run into the problem where a user recommends an out-dated tutorial, or old/insecure extension. We just don't know.

In the end, these types of questions can always be solved by a simple Google search. Example, in the path so many people have asked how to get the currently logged in username and display it.

> **Google** >> Joomla get logged in username

This will immediately provide you with the Joomla Documentation on the user object and what's available.

That said, I personally would not like to encourage these types of questions and thus don't agree with a tag for it.

This is however my opinion and other may disagree. Would be nice to hear other views :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that we are likely to continue to get these types of questions, but I don't think that we should do anything to encourage them (or even necessarily answer them in a lot of cases).

From the site tour:

```
Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced.
Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.
```

As much as we as a Joomla community want to help new coders understand Joomla and coding by sending people to resources and links that can help them, this isn't the best format to do it in.

Specifically, the difficulty is in maintenance and longevity. While there is a plan for Joomla docs maintenance and updates, there is no such plan for answers here. It's up to the community to discover that the old resources are wrong. How would this happen? Likely someone will post a duplicate question as the original (that has wrong info) and try to get a better answer. I'd be much more confident that the new question would get closed as a duplicate than that the old resources would be updated appropriately.

I would much rather see those questions directed to the google groups/forums and focus here on "I tried this and it doesn't work".